# How to convert retrofit response body into JsonObject

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

```
public abstract class RetrofitBaseCallBack<T> implements Callback<T> {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {
        int responseCode = response.code();
        if (responseCode == Constants.ServerResponse.Code.STATUS_OK
                || responseCode == Constants.ServerResponse.Code.STATUS_CREATED_SUCCESS
                || responseCode == Constants.ServerResponse.Code.STATUS_IN_PROGRESS
                || responseCode == Constants.ServerResponse.Code.STATUS_NO_CONTENT
                || responseCode == Constants.ServerResponse.Code.STATUS_ACCEPTED) {
            // i want to navigate to onResponseSuccess when "success":true
            onResponseSuccess(call, response);
        } else {
           //i want to navigate to onResponseFailure when "success":false
            onErrorResponse(call, response);
        }
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {
        onRetrofitBaseCallBackFailure(call, t);
    }

    public abstract void onResponseSuccess(Call<T> call, Response<T> response);

    public abstract void onResponseFailure(Call<T> call, Response response, String message);

    public abstract void onRetrofitBaseCallBackFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t);
}
```

I had made class by extending retrofit callback. I want to parse the response as string. In my case  every response gets the JSON object of this type. In the case of success response:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "abc": {
    "a": 0.15,
    "b": "Better Exchange Rate",
  }
}
```

In case of failure response

```
{
      "success": false,
      "abc": {
        "a": 0.15,
        "b": "Better Exchange Rate",
      }
    }
```

How can i convert response body into JsonObject so that i can check field **"success":** and navigate respective method i-e **onResponseSuccess(Call call, Response response)** in case of success ,**onResponseFailure(Call call, Response response, String message)** in case of failure

Answer (score 1):

How to get JSONObject from response.body() in retrofit:

```
try {

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());

} catch (JSONException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("TAG", "No valid json");

}
```